# Websphere Portal - How to retrieve portal title/friendly URL?

Tags: portal, websphere-portal

How do we get the friendly url or portal title using java?

For example if I go to websphere to put the title and friendly url, how do I exactly retrieve it (using jsp)

Comment: Where are you trying to get this? In portlet or in theme?

Comment: I trying to retrieve it in the portlet.

Answer (score 1):

The WebSphere Portal Server has concept of NavigationSelectionModel SPI that you can use to know about the current page.This SPI is used by the theme to know the page which should be displayed to the user.Can be used in portlet application. To get the page title / unique name where your portlet is getting rendered, here is the code:

Step 1. Include portal taglib on JSP

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tld/portal.tld" prefix="wps" %>
```

Step 2. Use `<wps:navigation>` tag.

```
<wps:navigation>
    <wps:navigationloop>
        <%if (wpsSelectionModel.isNodeSelected(wpsNavNode)){
            String pageTitle = com.ibm.wps.model.LocaleHelper.getTitle 
                   ((com.ibm.portal.Localized)wpsNavNode, request);
            String uniqueName = wpsNavNode.getContentNode().getObjectID().getUniqueName();         
            System.out.println("pageTitle : " + pageTitle);
            System.out.println("uniqueName : " + uniqueName);
        }%>
    </wps:navigationloop>
</wps:navigation>
```